# How do I achieve the desired frequency with a Colpitts oscillator?

Tags: circuit-design, rf, oscillator

I would like to build an oscillator with frequency variation from 50MHz to 100MHz.

I decided to use a Colpitts oscillator because I read that it is stable and easy to build.

I built the circuit as below. From the calculations it seems that the frequency for C2 = 8 pF should be 99 MHz, and for C2 = 30 pF ~54 MHz.  I can only achieve a frequency from 50 MHz to 60 MHz across the full range of C2. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

All the capacitors are C0G type.

[image]

Comment: At 50+ MHz I'd like to see what you actually built, not an idealized schematic. Picture please...

Comment: m = milli; M = mega

Comment: Colpitts exceeding an octave is VERY non-trivial. Even if you can keep the parasitics down enough to get the variation of the centre frequency of your LC, the 4:1 C variation will upset the gain from end to end.

Answer (score 4):

> *I would like to build an oscillator with frequency variation from 50
> MHz to 100 MHz*

With a trimmer that goes from 8 pF to 30 pF in series with a 200 pF (C4), the net capacitance is from 7.69 pF to 26.09 pF. That's a ratio change of 3.393. To understand how the frequency might change we take the square root and get 1.84.

So, theoretically if one end of the trimmer produced 50 MHz then the other end would produce 92 MHz. So, if you want a 2:1 change you are in trouble already.

Then we also have to consider parasitic capacitance. Typically, for the [BFR93A](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BFR93A.pdf) (a good choice) we have: -

[image]

So, immediately we can see that there is 0.7 pF (Cc) in parallel with your tuning capacitor. This reduces the Cmin to Cmax tuning ratio a bit more. The feedback capacitance (Cre) also has an effect but this can be multiplied by circuit gain and be more pronounced that Cc.

Then you have the parasitic capacitance of your inductor that also reduces the effective ratio of Cmax to Cmin. Any capacitance from the output to GND has exactly the same effect.

So, maybe there is another 3 pF in parallel and, this takes Cmin to 10.69 pF and Cmax to 29.09 pF. That's a ratio of 2.72 and, the square root is 1.65. That means a tuning range of 50 MHz to 82.5 MHz.

Do, you see how these things can compound? Of course, if you are using solderless breadboard it's going to be a whole lot worse.

Answer (score 1):

A good start
The basic circuit is very similar to [Heathkit HD-1250](https://scharkalvin.weebly.com/heathkit-hd1250-dipmeter.html) "gate"-dip oscillator.
 Be aware that designing for octave frequency range (50MHz - 100 MHz) is not easy. One of Heathkit's plug-in coils (L1) spans such a frequency range. Stray inductance and stray capacitance can limit the span.
 Note that Heathkit's circuit uses a variable capacitor (C2a, C2b) consisting of two gangs, each of similar capacitance, instead of one variable capacitor as used in OP's circuit. Don't expect a linear frequency range as C2 is rotated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFxwq6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>